# Wait function finish in if

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to do a test but it does not wait to make the request in the database and it looks like the function returns undefined and only after the request it returns true or false and the test falls on the else.

My problem is in RestService of angular 4/5

function in which you perform the password validation to perform an update

```
    handler: data => {
      if (this.checkPassword(data.password)) {
        console.log("4--------");
        // logged in!
        let jsonCreate = {
            name: form.value.inputName,
            email: form.value.inputEmail,
            password: form.value.inputPassword,
            description: form.value.inputDescription,
            id: this.id
        };
        console.log('jsonCreate');
        console.log(jsonCreate);
        //adiciona cliente ao banco
        this.rest.put('usersClient/atualizacao', jsonCreate)
        .subscribe(userUpdated => {
            console.log(userUpdated);

        });
      } else {
        console.log("3--------");
        return false;
      }
    }
```

check password func

```
  }
  public checkPassword(password){
      console.log("check");

    let jsonPost = {};
    jsonPost["email"] = this.user.email;
    jsonPost["senha"] = password;
    console.log(jsonPost);
    this.rest.post('Login/clientAuth', jsonPost).subscribe(user => {
        console.log("11--------");
        if(this.isEmptyObject(user)==true){
            console.log("1--------");
          return false;
        }
        else{
            console.log("2--------");
            return true;

        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to wait for the async action, you must return the observable that `this.rest.post` creates:

```
public checkPassword(password){
    ...
    return this.rest.post('Login/clientAuth', "").map(user => !this.isEmptyObject(user));
});
```

And then, subscribe to this observable in `data`:

```
handler: data => {
    this.checkPassword(data.password).subscribe(isLoggedIn => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            let jsonCreate = {
                ...
            };

            this.rest.put('usersClient/atualizacao', jsonCreate).subscribe(userUpdated => {
                console.log(userUpdated);
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Note: if you also need to wait for the `put` action outside `data`, you cannot subscribe to `checkPassword`. You need to do something like this:

```
handler: data => {
    this.checkPassword(data.password).flatMap(isLoggedIn => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            let jsonCreate = {
                ...
            };
            return this.rest.put('usersClient/atualizacao', jsonCreate).map(userUpdated => {
                console.log(userUpdated);
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And subscribe to `data`

Comment: this error show in subscribe "[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?"

Comment: Did you change the `subscribe` to `map` after `this.rest.post('Login/clientAuth', "")`?

Comment: wow, its work now sorry for the lack of attention, thank you, you were incredible, I lost six hours trying to solve it.

Comment: glad I was able to help